# 3D rotation dilemma 

Tags: 3d, rotation, linear-algebra

OK, hopefully I can explain this in a comprehensive fashion...forgive me if I confuse you thoroughly...

I am using an old annoying engine that applies a rotation matrix to the object using only local-space.

I have a text tool that allows users (non-programmers) to create objects and rotate them (changes are not applied in real time).

The rotations will be fine if only 1 axis is rotated about, but of course will become cockeyed when they specify rotation about 2 axes (such as rotation about the UP and RIGHT) because the rotations about the UP is applied using the local UP and not the global (i.e. world) UP.

For example, say we have a camera (0,0,0) looking at the broad side of a plane (0,-5,0). The user of the tool wants to rotate that plane about it's X (RIGHT) 45 degrees, and about the global UP 45 degrees. Well, I have no way of letting them simply specify 2 rotation values and getting their desired rotation about the global UP...they are required to, by trial-and-error, specify rotation about the FORWARD (Y in this case) in order to keep the object "upright".

What I'm wondering is: how can I convert rotations about 2 axes, into rotations about 3 axes, assuming that rotations about the UP are the global UP, and still attain the rotation that the user would envision.

Comment: I'm assuming something like (east,north,up) so (0,0,-5) is five units below the origin, and your camera is looking down at it. At this point I don't understand your rotations, but tell me if this is what you want. You first want to tilt the north end of the plane up 45 deg, and then rotate the plane around the old up axis (not the current normal to the plane)?

Comment: Sorry, I had the plane position wrong, which I've corrected. The plane would just be directly in front of the camera, with the camera having no rotation. The plane's normal is facing the camera.

In the example, the user wants to tilt the plane's top away from the camera, and rotate it about the global UP (0,0,1 in this case).

Comment: Rotate them in the opposite order.  With 2 consecutive rotations, one will always be on the local side, and the other will always be on the global side.  So, if the one you're currently using is on the wrong side, use the other instead.

Comment: You know, I thought about that, but then for some reason I dismissed it thinking the problem was in how the engine applied the rotation. But yeah, that indeed does the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The local coordinate frame for each object is fixed to it, so as soon as you rotate the object's local axes away from the global axes, rotation about the global axes (say global up) becomes an arbitrary rotation with respect to the local axes.

So if you want to allow users to rotate about global up, you'll need to figure out the right combination of rotations / translations about the local axes of the object.

A google search for `rotation about arbitrary axis` came up with this link:

http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/

Comment: So just to be clear - what you're proposing would allow the user to specify just the 2 rotations (say X & Z rotations), and then take those 2 values and build a rotation matrix that would have the correct rotation values for what would be a rotation about all 3 local axes??

Comment: More or less. I'm thinking the problem you have to solve is given an arbitrary axis (any axis, but in particular global up) how do you rotate an object about that axis when you know the components of that arbitrary axis relative to a fixed coordinate system (your local coordinate system).

Comment: Yeah, makes sense...I'll dive in that direction. Thanks!